# GTK+ 1.2 toolkit

Tags: gtk

I install a program that need 'GTK+ 1.2 toolkit' package but can't find it in synaptic. This toolkit is old I guess. Could someone suggest me a package alternative to this one?

The program I try to install is GSView4.9 which requires GTK+ 1.2 toolkit!

Comment: Google tells me GSView 4.9 is ten years old and GTK 1.2 is no longer supported. Furthermore the latest GSView (5.0) is 5 years old and no longer supports *nix, so I am guessing GSView is getting stagnant. I would check for alternative software.

Comment: @theGtknerd Thank you for that, though I have found an alternative solution. The newest Ghostscript 9.21 and GSView 5.0 could be installed on WINE with no problem and work fine.